# How to make a comment box like facebook?

Tags: jquery, facebook, textarea

I want to make a comment box like facebook. When I click on this box (onfocus), the cursor will blink at the head of the line. And when I press combination Shift + Enter, it will begin a newline and the textarea will expand.

Comment: Lets see - how to make a comment box... you'll need some programming, and some design, some time set asside... yea...  -1, people will not do the work for you.  Jump right in, try doing something by yourself - and when/if you run into some problems come here and post a more specific question.

Comment: My english is not good, so I cant figure out what i mean clearly.
I am buiding my personal page using PHP, HTML5 and jQuery. I want my page have comment boxes similar to facebook. But I dont know how to make it. You may just show me the suggestion, not actual code. Here is what I want:
1. when I click on comment box, the cursor wil return the head of line. Now, can click every where on the textarea although I havent type any characters yet.
2. When I hit Shift + enter it will begin a new line, and the text area will expand so that i can see all I've typed

Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is for you to search on the internet.  People will **not** do google searches for you.   Break your problem in to **smaller parts** and deal with each one **separately**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once tried it, and here is the link i followed. This one is complete wallpost post system. You can download the code and see it for yourself
http://www.9lessons.info/2011/05/facebook-wall-script-with-php-and.html

Comment: Not a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This [jQuery plug in](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/) can give you the idea how to make your `textarea` auto resizable.

You can listen to Enter key for submitting your comment and allow Shift + Enter work like normal Enter key press.

```
yourtextare.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
   if(event.which === 13 && !event.shiftKey){
      //submit your comment via AJAX or anything you like
   }
}, false);
```

your